# Than vs But usage

Tags: prepositions

> 1. I didn’t see any other person **than** your brother.
> 2. I didn’t see any other person **but** your brother.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: I think we are talking about a fixed expression here : other....than [prepositional meaning] e.g. The guy was none other than my brother. OR I don't want anything other than her. Would you rather say "rather than" than "rather but"? Nonetheless, if you want to add meaning to the latter, use "but for" which has the meaning of "except for". You are introducing an exception or contrast in the former.

Answer (score 1):

"Other than" means except / but.

The sentence sounds good if you say :

> I didn't see any person **other than** / **except** / **but** your brother.

Or,

> I saw **none other than** your brother.

Or,

> I saw **none but** your brother.